# Was the "hole in the ozone" caused by CFCs?

Tags: environment

Burt Rutan (the aviator) has put out a critique of climate change:

[An Engineer's Critique of Global Warming "Science"](http://rps3.com/Files/AGW/EngrCritique.AGW-Science.v4.3.pdf)

On page 7, this caught my eye:

> Modern Human-Extinction Scares
>
> ...
>
> • Hole in the Ozone layer, caused by CFCs, 1970s & 1980s
> (We now know that the Ozone changes were not caused by human CFCs)

I seem to have missed that memo.  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ozone_depletion) still mentions CFCs as a cause.

> The details of polar ozone hole formation differ from that of mid-latitude thinning, but the most important process in both is catalytic destruction of ozone by atomic halogens. The main source of these halogen atoms in the stratosphere is photodissociation of man-made halocarbon refrigerants (CFCs, freons, halons). These compounds are transported into the stratosphere after being emitted at the surface. Both types of ozone depletion were observed to increase as emissions of halo-carbons increased.

Is there any credible backing for Mr. Rutan's offhand claim?

Comment: I find no sign of a challenge to the prevailing chlorofluorocarbon mechanism over the past three years at Google scholar:
http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=ozone+hole+chlorofluorocarbons&as_sdt=0%2C28&as_ylo=2009&as_vis=0

There is much confirmation that CFC's remain the culprit.

Comment: He puts a *We now know* without giving an explanation, let alone some proper reference. Sounds to me like "trust me, although I don't have any proof it must be like that because it was a government plot".

Comment: As an engineer, I am deeply embarrassed that Ruttan would decide to critique something outside his field like this for political reasons...

Comment: @LarianLeQuella But his general argument that adapting to warming is more useful than trying vainly to prevent it is not that bad and, as an engineer, he is on a topic of relevance to his skills.

Comment: Excepting of course that he has NO CLUE that any and all efforts will be in vain. He presumes that, and it's a totally inappropriate presumption on his part. He, and the many others who display this attitude seem to have not only made themselves victims of Learned helplessness, but want the rest of us to be its victims too. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learned_helplessness

Comment: He isn't quite alone in his views: http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/science-environment-16439807

Comment: Comments are not for chat or the expression of political views.  Can we please keep the comments that serve no constructive purpose to chat.

Comment: Mr Rutan's presentation is fill of errors and misunderstandings (e.g. only 3% of CO2 is anthropogenic), and expressed in a hyperbolic tone (CAGW, alarmists etc.) that ought to suggest skepticism is warranted.  Fortunately his planes are more reliable than his science.

Answer (score 16):

**While the consensus is that CFCs cause the ozone hole, there is recent evidence that we don't understand it as well as we thought**

When I first read the Rutan comments I though he had simply gone nuts in his general skeptical approach to scares (on Skeptics.se we should applaud his skeptical approach unless his evidence is nonsense), but then I uncovered some recent science that might give *some grounds* for his claim (though not the degree of certainty he expresses).

As far as I can tell the original source is from a [Nature news story](http://www.nature.com/news/2007/070924/full/449382a.html) in 2007 which points out that some recent reevaluations of the reaction kinetics of some of the key reactions involved in ozone depletion had given radically different results to those used in the original models of ozone depletion. As one of the scientists reviewing the results said:

> If the measurements are correct we can basically no longer say we understand how ozone holes come into being.

This view had widespread coverage in the press and blogs. But perhaps the most significant comment on a related topic was by James Lovelock and reported on [this blog](http://wattsupwiththat.com/2011/01/08/new-rate-of-stratospheric-photolysis-questions-ozone-hole/). Lovelock (intimately involved in the science as he invented the key method for detecting small amounts of things like CFCs) is commenting on the recently revealed Climategate emails and their implication of disreputable behaviour by some climate scientists:

> We should have been warned by the CFC/ozone affair because the corruption of science in that was so bad that something like 80% of the measurements being made during that time were either faked, or incompetently done.

His comments are interesting as they suggest we reached consensus on the ozone hole a little quickly and, once the bandwagon was established a lot of poor science was done (which, despite being a believer in the consensus of global warming he also thinks is happening there).

More significantly his comments have been widely reported in climate-related blogs and might be read as arguing that CFCs didn't cause the hole. A more careful reading would be that though most experts think they did, *we are no longer clear how.*

Comment: To be fair, the article also says that: "The new measurements raise “intriguing questions”, but don't compromise the Montreal Protocol as such, says John Pyle, an atmosphere researcher at the University of Cambridge. “We're starting to see the benefits of the protocol, but we need to keep the pressure on.” He says that he finds it “extremely hard to believe” that an unknown mechanism accounts for the bulk of observed ozone losses."

Comment: Ozone depletion is a 4 step process which has a dark/light phase and occurs in the stratosphere.  In darkness, phase 1: there is a formation of polar and stratospheric clouds of HNO3 and H2O, which in phase 2 spurs the activation of Clx compounds (ClONO2, HOCl, N2O5, HCl) which produces Cl2 and HOCl.  In the spring sun, those compounds react with light to form ClOx compounds: Cl2 + hv -> 2Cl, HOCl + hv -> OH + Cl, Cl + O3 -> ClO + O2, which in step four cause catalytic ozone depletion: ClO + ClO -> Cl2O2, Cl2O2 + hv -> 2Cl + O2, Cl + O3 -> ClO + O2 which continues cycling and consuming O3.

Comment: Reference to the above: Chemistry and the Environment, S.E. Harnung and M. S. Johnson.

Comment: I personally don't find ad-hominems against scientists and accusations of deception to be a satisfactory answer to what is a scientific question.  Answers like this tend to raise my skepticism, rather than answer it.

Comment: Since the core of the answer is about recent scientific results and they imply a certain carelessness in previous results, I don't think the answer is merely an *ad hominem* attack on anyone. And *deception* isn't what is alleged, it is *carelessness* or *shoddy technique*. These are important issues unless you believe scientists form some new, privileged, priesthood and cannot be criticised.

Comment: The quote from Lovelock says that some results were faked, that *is* very obviously an accusation of deception.  The second part of your answer is just an ad-hominem with no real evidence that any results were actually faked.

Comment: @DikranMarsupial He says *faked **or** incompetent*. And the modern paper suggests he was right. The modern results and the old results can't both be true; pick an explanation that doesn't mean scientists screwed up or lied.

Comment: @DikranMarsupial I should also point out that I'm not arguing that Rutan was right. CFCs most likely caused the hole, but our belief we understood the detail of *how* was clearly overconfident.

Comment: @matt_black, saying that results were "either faked, or incompetently done" is still an accusation of deception on the part of those producing the faked results, but not the producers of the "incompetently done" results.  As I said, the more you try to use rhetoric (e.g. " These are important issues unless you believe scientists form some new, privileged, priesthood and cannot be criticised") instead of discussing the actual scientific point, the less satisfying your argument is.

Comment: I have no problem with the idea that there has been over-confidence in scientific understanding of CFCs, the point I am making is that the ad-hominems and accusations of deception in your answer detract from the point you are making about the science, and only serve to make the discussion partisan and rhetorical, rather than neutral and scientific.

Comment: @matt_black according to google scholar only 85 papers have cited the paper mentioned in the Nature article (55 according to web of science).  If it really did cast serious doubt on our understanding of the ozone hole (the subject of a good deal of scientific study) then I would expect rather more citations.  This is possibly because one of the papers that cites it seems to show that it was actually consistent with existing ozone degradation models http://science.sciencemag.org/content/324/5928/781.full and hence the news article a bit overstated (to say the least).

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is indeed. The ozone hole is still there, and will not recover for another 40 years. Meanwhile, CFCs and other ozone depletion substances (ODS) are banned by the [Montreal Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montreal_Protocol).

A 2011 study on the implementation of the Montreal protocol and the effectiveness of the ban is "[Science and Diplomacy: Montreal Protocol on Substances that Deplete the Ozone Layer](http://www.atsummit50.org/media/book-17.pdf)":

> The Montreal Protocol on Substances that Deplete the Ozone Layer seeks worldwide phaseout of the production and consumption of ODS. Scientists confirmed that the protocol is working and that the ozone layer is on its way to recovery around the year 2050.

[The Ozone Hole](http://www.theozonehole.com/2011.htm) web site provides reporting on the ozone layer hole, and as you can see, it's still there in 2011.

[image: Ozone Hole 2011]

Then, there is the UN-backed "[International Day for the Presevation of the Ozone Layer](http://www.unep.org/ozonaction/Events/OzoneDay/2011/OzoneDay2011CountryActivities/tabid/56221/Default.aspx)", to keep the attention up. In reality, HCFCs are hundreds of different substances that need to be phased out. We are gradually getting there.

Comment: Although you cited very good refs about what has been done to fix the problem, I think your answer does not really tackle the problem of "what caused the ozone hole"? The fact that removing CFC makes the hole get smaller does not imply that the CFC were the cause (correlation is not causation).

Comment: What we are trying to disprove here is: "We now know that the Ozone changes were not caused by human CFCs". That is just false as we are still phasing out HCFCs to fix the ozone layer. Your point about correlation/causation doesn't make sense. We proved correlation when we showed high concentrations of CFCs correlated with low ozone. We proved causation once we demonstrated that removing CFCs (a single variable change) increases the ozone.

Comment: As much as I do believe CFC were the cause, I personally don't think that "a single variable change" was what we did. So many things have changed in the last 30 years in terms of how we care for the environment, and some of those may have also affected the ozone hole. Earth is not a gigantic lab where you can change one single variable. Maybe CFCs were causing something else to produce an ozonolytic subtance. What you should really show is some study showing, for instance, that CFCs can break up ozone, they should not be difficult to find.

Comment: Is the [1995 Nobel Prize in Chemistry](http://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/chemistry/laureates/1995/) enough proof?

Comment: sure, that is a very good reference. If you can find the actual papers that would be even better

Comment: @nico: the actual papers will only produce a theory. Experimental proof is ample, due to many different papers, but the most convincing by far is the success of the Montreal protocol, of which you seem (for some reason) skeptical. Nobels to theorists are only given after the theory is proven beyond doubt.

Comment: I am not skeptical of the Montreal protocol, nor of the fact that CFC caused the ozone hole. I am just telling you how I would improve your answer so that it gave a more complete view of the problem. If someone asks me what causes flu I don't answer that vaccination can prevent it. The Montreal protocol is based on a wide range of scientific studies, pick some significant ones and you'll have a more complete answer.

Comment: I think that we disagree on what the question is asking: I am simply proving that it is false that "We now know that the Ozone changes were not caused by human CFCs". In this context, providing a link to a paper from the 80's is not going to address the claim. That is why I linked a 2011 study and not the original ones.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really much into the subject, so could someone explain: if human produced CFCs are too blame,  why is the ozone hole located over the non-populated continent in the middle of less populated hemisphere? Wouldn't it be expected to be much bigger on northern hemisphere, given that most developed countries which were using CFCs are located there?

Comment: @vartec it's due to the circulation of the atmosphere.

Comment: @Sklivvz: which would explain why it's over the poles, but why more over south pole, than north pole, if most CFCs were produced in the north hemisphere?

Comment: @vartec I have no clue as to why, however I know that CFCs in the atmosphere have been measured directly, and that CFCs do not exist in nature, they are only of artificial origin IIRC

Comment: @Sklivvz: well, thing is that it's not CFCs, but halogens contained withing them, that affect ozone. There are natural sources of halogens (eg. chloromethane from oceanic biomass). For example it's produced by algae like *Gigartina skottsbergii* which grows (surprise) in the antarctic region.

Comment: @vartec sure - cfcs are converted to halogens by UVs in the troposphere, So their concentration is still known. The other answer mentions some doubts about the rate at which this happens. There is no doubt that I know of that CFCs do concentrate at the south pole.

Answer (score -3):

alas ... since oxygen-2 is diamagnetic it will be attracted to the poles. the more oxygen-2 up there the larger the area or volume of the oxygen-2.
when oxygen-3 breaks down into oxygen-2 the -2 heads to the poles and forces the -3 away from the poles forming a 'hole' for lack of better terms.

oxygen-3 (Ozone) breaks down for many reasons. CFCs are just one. but the problem is the chlorine is a catalyst and can cause a geometrically larger increase for contribution than say CME coronal mass ejections. the shift to FCs has helped return the o-2/0-3 to the natural state.